# Navigation Drawer whith ListView. Null Point Exception on ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview, navigation-drawer

i'm following this [tutorial](https://androidbelieve.com/navigation-drawer-with-swipe-tabs-using-design-support-library/), for an Drawer Menu and a tab layout. So i have created the xml file for the menu, but i wouldn't use item but a ListView. Here is the xml code of the menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/listView"
   android:layout_gravity="center" />
</menu>
```

Here is the xml code of the activity:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:title="Drawer With Swipe Tabs" />



<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">

    </FrameLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is the MainActivity java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter;
List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getModel());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private List getModel() {
    list.add(new Model("ISPEZIONE"));
    return list;
}
}
```

I have the null point exeption on the ListView. So i know because have the problem (I had the same problem with fragments) but i cant' resolve it with a menu. How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ListView in your activity view hierarchy, so findViewById returns null (which causes your crash). If you want to use a ListView rather than NavigationView, just replace the NavigationView element with a fragment/FrameLayout that contains a ListView.

Comment: Such like this? http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Yep, that should work correctly if you follow the steps in that tutorial

Comment: To make a Navigation Drawer there are two methds, the first with the first tutorial that i have linked and the secondo method with the other tutorial that have linked.. The secondo method have already done, and it work fine. I would test the first method, without items but with a listVew,  but i can't male a reference at the ListView..